# Trim/Autofit on Change Efficiently

Tags: excel, vba, onchange, trim, intersect

I modified an existing on-change macro in a sheet to automatically trim and autofit columns whenever a cell in a range is changed. It works, but I had two questions I was hoping to find answers for here: is there a way to set the targeted range to whatever range was just edited (only one cell if one cell had data manually entered, and the range of whatever was pasted when a range is posted inside a specific range); and is there any way to make the code I already have more efficient?

It's a request form that often has multiple names/ID's that's used by both me and others, and more often than not the user is copying and pasting over a range of 4 columns with 30-ish rows at a time rather than one by one. There are a couple of IF's in there to check if it's me, and that's just because I receive the form from others and then turn around and send it to a client, so I didn't want to have to hit unprotect every time I received one if something was incorrect.

Here's the code as-is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim KeyCells2 As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("B13:c14")
Set KeyCells2 = Range("B13:E113")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets("Request Sheet").Unprotect
    Range("b4").Value = "=Now()"
    If Right(Environ("userprofile"), 7) <> [my pc userprofile name here] Then
        Worksheets("Request Sheet").Protect
    End If
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells2, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    For Each cell In Range("B13:" & Cells(WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B13:B113")) + 12, WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B13:E13")) + 1).Address)
        cv = cell.Value
        If Right(cell, 1) = " " Or Left(cell, 1) = " " Then
            cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cv)
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Rows(cell.Row).EntireRow.AutoFit
        If Rows(cell.Row).RowHeight <> 15.75 Then
        With ActiveSheet
            .Rows(cell.Row).RowHeight = 15.75
            .Columns(cell.Column).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
        End If
        If Columns(2).ColumnWidth < 18.75 Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 18.75
        Else: ActiveSheet.Columns(2).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Columns(3).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        If Columns(3).ColumnWidth < 15.14 Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(3).ColumnWidth = 15.14
        End If
        If Columns(4).ColumnWidth < 17.43 Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(4).ColumnWidth = 17.43
        End If
        If Columns(5).ColumnWidth < 13.86 Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(5).ColumnWidth = 13.86
        End If
    Next
    ActiveSheet.Rows(9).RowHeight = 24
    ActiveSheet.Rows(10).RowHeight = 19.5
    ActiveSheet.Rows(11).RowHeight = 26.25
    ActiveSheet.Rows(12).RowHeight = 42.75
    If Right(Environ("userprofile"), 7) <> [my pc userprofile name here] Then
        ActiveSheet.Protect
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: `Range(Target.Address)` -> `Target`.

Comment: Check the column widths *outside* the loop.

Comment: `cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cv)` - it looks like that will re-trigger the event, so you should disable/enable events.